# Can I use perltidy's HTML formatter in my automated Perl build?

Tags: html, perl, build-process, build, perl-tidy

I'm using Module::Build to perform build, test, testpod, html, & install actions on my Perl module that I'm developing.  The HTML files that are generated are okay, but I'd be much happier if I could somehow configure Module::Build to use the perltidy -html formatting utility instead of its own HTML formatter.

Anyone know of a way I can replace the HTML formatter that comes with Module::Build with the prettier perltidy HTML formatter?

***Addendum:***  When I said "replace" above, that was probably misleading.  I don't really want to write code to replace the html formatter that comes with Module::Build.  I really want to know if Module::Build has any **other** HTML formatter options.  The HTML it generates is so plain and generic looking.  It's so boring.  I like perltidy's output a lot.

Here is how I got it working right now in a build script that I wrote, but it's totally a hack ... falling out to the command line perltidy script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# get list of files in directory
my $libLocation = "lib/EDF";
opendir( DIR, $libLocation );
my @filenameArray = readdir(DIR);

# iterate over all files to find *.pm set
for my $file (@filenameArray) {
    if ( $file =~ m/      # matching regex
                      \.  # literal period character
                      pm  # the pm file extenstion
                  /x      # end of regex
       )
    {

        my $return = `perl D:/Perl/site/bin/perltidy -q --indent-columns=4 --maximum-line-length=80 -html -opath blib/libhtml2 -toc $libLocation/$file`;

        if ($return eq "") {
            print "HTMLized " . $file . "\n";
        }
        else {
            print "Error: " . $return . "\n";
        }

    }

}
```

But I was really hoping there was a way to use Module::Build and just tell it with a flag or an argument or whatever to tell it to use a different HTML formatter.  I guess that's a pipe dream, though:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Module::Build;

my $build = Module::Build->resume (
  properties => {
    config_dir => '_build',
  },
);

$build->dispatch('build');
$build->dispatch('html', engine => 'perltidy');
```

or maybe:

```
$build->dispatch('htmltidy');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the action is implemented in

```
htmlify_pods
```

in [Module::Build::Base](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/EWILHELM/Module-Build-0.33/lib/Module/Build/Base.pm).

It should be possible to override that method.

**Much Later ...**

Here is my attempt (tested only once):

```
package My::Builder;

use strict;
use warnings;

use base 'Module::Build';

sub htmlify_pods {
  my $self = shift;
  my $type = shift;
  my $htmldir = shift || File::Spec->catdir($self->blib, "${type}html");

  require Module::Build::Base;
  require Module::Build::PodParser;
  require Perl::Tidy;

  $self->add_to_cleanup('pod2htm*');

  my $pods = $self->_find_pods( 
      $self->{properties}{"${type}doc_dirs"},
      exclude => [ Module::Build::Base::file_qr('\.(?:bat|com|html)$') ] );
  return unless %$pods;  # nothing to do

  unless ( -d $htmldir ) {
    File::Path::mkpath($htmldir, 0, oct(755))
      or die "Couldn't mkdir $htmldir: $!";
  }

  my @rootdirs = ($type eq 'bin') ? qw(bin) :
      $self->installdirs eq 'core' ? qw(lib) : qw(site lib);

  my $podpath = join ':',
                map  $_->[1],
                grep -e $_->[0],
                map  [File::Spec->catdir($self->blib, $_), $_],
                qw( script lib );

  foreach my $pod ( keys %$pods ) {

    my ($name, $path) = File::Basename::fileparse($pods->{$pod},
        Module::Build::Base::file_qr('\.(?:pm|plx?|pod)$'));
    my @dirs = File::Spec->splitdir( File::Spec->canonpath( $path ) );
    pop( @dirs ) if $dirs[-1] eq File::Spec->curdir;

    my $fulldir = File::Spec->catfile($htmldir, @rootdirs, @dirs);
    my $outfile = File::Spec->catfile($fulldir, "${name}.html");
    my $infile  = File::Spec->abs2rel($pod);

    next if $self->up_to_date($infile, $outfile);

    unless ( -d $fulldir ){
      File::Path::mkpath($fulldir, 0, oct(755))
        or die "Couldn't mkdir $fulldir: $!";
    }

    my $path2root = join( '/', ('..') x (@rootdirs+@dirs) );
    my $htmlroot = join( '/',
             ($path2root,
              $self->installdirs eq 'core' ? () : qw(site) ) );

    my $fh = IO::File->new($infile) or die "Can't read $infile: $!";
    my $abstract = Module::Build::PodParser->new(fh => $fh)->get_abstract();

    my $title = join( '::', (@dirs, $name) );
    $title .= " - $abstract" if $abstract;

    my %opts = (
        argv => join(" ", 
            qw( -html --podflush ),
            "--title=$title",
            '--podroot='.$self->blib,
            "--htmlroot=$htmlroot",
            "--podpath=$podpath",
        ),
        source => $infile,
        destination => $outfile,
    );

    if ( eval{Pod::Html->VERSION(1.03)} ) {
      $opts{argv} .= ' --podheader';
      $opts{argv} .= ' --backlink=Back to Top';
      if ( $self->html_css ) {
          $opts{argv} .= " --css=$path2root/" . $self->html_css;
      }
    }

    $self->log_info("HTMLifying $infile -> $outfile\n");
    $self->log_verbose("perltidy %opts\n");
    Perl::Tidy::perltidy(%opts);    # or warn "pod2html @opts failed: $!";
  }
}
1;
```

** To use it .. **

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use My::Builder;

my $builder = My::Builder->new(
    module_name => 'My::Test',
    license     => 'perl',
);

$builder->create_build_script;
```

Comment: That sounds like work I'm not comfortable taking on.   I was hoping there was just a flag I could set or something.  :-)

Comment: It probably isn't that hard. I'll take a look later.

Comment: This is interesting.  I'm assuming that you just changed the last line from whatever it used to be to this perltidy call.  My worry here is that this is for a work project, and I'd be copying an existing CPAN subroutine and freezing it forever and never getting the benefit of any future Module::Build upgrades to this particular routine.  Not a really good software engineering proactice.  Might not be a big deal for this one small case, though.  I'll consider it.  Thanks for showing me how to do it.

Comment: I also changed how the options were built. I also filed http://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=45830

Your comment about upgrades is confusing to me. I am not recommending that you go and actually edit the installed Module-Build files. This is a subclass of Module::Build that overrides one method. If you upgrade the installed Module-Build, you get to inherit from the upgraded library. The only thing that is overridden is this particular method. In the mean time, if a future version Module-Build provides the required functionality, you get rid of My::Builder.

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy to define new Module::Build actions that you can call with dispatch, and there are plenty of examples in the Module::Build documentation. Define an action to handle your new step:

```
sub ACTION_htmltidy
    {
    my( $self ) = @_;

    $self->depends_on( ...other targets... );

    require Perl::Tidy;

    ...do your damage...
    }
```

If you want another action to use yours, you can extend it so you can make the dependency:

```
sub ACTION_install
    {
    my( $self ) = @_;

    $self->depends_on( 'htmltidy' );

    $self->SUPER::install;
    }
```

Comment: So in the "do your damage" section, I would put in my code that reads my library directory and parses out the list of PM files and then processes each PM file using more code that I write?  Aren't I doing a bunch of work there in the "do your damage" section that Module::Build already knows how to do?  Doesn't seem like the right thing to do to me.

Comment: @Kurt: you'd be using the Module::Build API, so you'd be reusing the stuff that Module::Build already knows how to do.